# create a hashmap with key of integer and value of a hashset of integers

Tags: java

I have the task to create a hashmap with integer keys and values of type "hashset of integers". For now, I tried the following:

```
HashMap hm= new HashMap(Integer, new HashSet<>());
```

I got an error which told me that cannot find symbol Integer. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here how you should declare your map:

```
Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>(); // In Java SE 7, you can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>)
Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>(); // version of jdk prior to 7
```